# Real World strtod(); for use with WINAPI textbox

Tags: .net, c++, winapi

ResultBox1->Text  = (sin(TextBox1->Text)) * TextBox2->Text

That is what i would like to work, but im dealing with Strings 
 I cant seem to convert the strings, do the trig, and convert back to string for displaying properly... anyone with an example?

Comment: How I hate WinAPI... it makes the easy things hard, and the hard things harder... -_-

Comment: Retagged for .net because the poster added a comment later describing .net code instead of winapi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System::Convert::ToDouble(TextBox1->Text)
```

You said you're trying to convert a System::String^ so this should work for you.

Comment: error C2664: 'atof' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'const char *'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          Cannot convert a managed type to an unmanaged type

Comment: @Smoka:  You are not using the WinAPI then; you're using .NET.

Comment: System::Convert::ToDouble(TextBox1->Text) then?

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble converting strings it might be because the string encoding might not be what you thought it was.  If you use _tcstod and datatypes such as LPTSTR then you can cope with either ANSI or Unicode.

Edit:  This answer was given when the question was asking about winapi.  Now the poster has clarified that the question intended to ask about .net, so this answer is irrelevant.